# Convert h264 file to mp4 with OpenCV's cudacodec

Tags: c++, opencv

I am experimenting OpenCV's integration with CUDA (`cv::cudacodec`) using the official example [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/gpu/video_writer.cpp). The sample code works. However, it seems to me that the resultant file generated by `cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoWriter>` is an H264 file, without a proper container such as mp4/avi.

My question is whether or not there is a recommended way to wrap the h264 file (say in-memory?) into a proper mp4/avi file.

I can think of one circuitous approach to achieve this–apart from building OpenCV with `cv::cudacodec`, we firstly build FFmpeg with Nvidia Video codec and then build OpenCV with this particular FFmpeg build, then we use `cv::VideoWriter`’s FFmpeg backend to leverage hardware codec. But wondering if there is a more straightforward way…

Comment: try the opencv forum. there are people with experience in that part of the library.

Comment: why not getting cv::Mat s in a loop and encoding them into a mp4/avi file ? if the point is only converting h264 to mp4 then you may directly use `ffmpeg -i input.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4`

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I want to use my GPU. If I am not mistaken, `d_writer` from the above link directly encodes raw frames that reside in GPU memory (referenced by a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` variable) to file system.

Comment: I think the VideoWriter in cudacodec is obsolete. you're supposed to use `cv::VideoWriter`. it has been extended in recent years to be able to use hardware acceleration, if you specify the right parameters. please browse the opencv forum.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz any source of what you said? According to doc of OpenCV 4.x [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dde/classcv_1_1cudacodec_1_1VideoWriter.html), `cv::cudacodec::VideoWriter` is not obsolete.

Comment: thank you for seeking out the CUDA pros in the forum. for reference: https://forum.opencv.org/t/convert-h264-file-to-mp4-with-cv-cudacodec/14313

Comment: @toyotaSupra, no, they are just totally different. please read my question carefully before casting your vote.

Answer (score 1):

After posting the same question to OpenCV's forum [here](https://forum.opencv.org/t/convert-h264-file-to-mp4-with-cv-cudacodec/14313/27), an [OpenCV developer](https://forum.opencv.org/u/cudawarped/summary) added this feature to the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) repository in this [PR](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/3569).

A simple working example can be found [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/tree/main/c-cpp/cpp-only/06_poc/05_cuda-vs-ffmpeg).